# Grouping arrays in php and count data

Tags: php, arrays

Recently I am working on a project that categorises 'Superheros' and 'Supervillains' based on their 'Franchaise' and origin of 'Superpower'. I want to fetch data from database as as Array #1 and displays them as Array #2 in php.

```
 Array #1

Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 101
      [Name] => Superman
      [Franchise] => DC Comics
      [Superpower] => Inherent
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [id] => 908
      [Name] => Batman
      [Franchise] => DC Comics
      [Superpower] => Acquired
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [id] => 228
      [Name] => Wolverine
      [Franchise] => Marvel
      [Superpower] => Acquired
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
      [id] => 158
      [Name] => Iron Man
      [Franchise] => Marvel
      [Superpower] => Acquired
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
      [id] => 978
      [Name] => Thor
      [Franchise] => Marvel
      [Superpower] => Inherent
    )
)
```

Array #1 elements have to be grouped based on their 'Franchise' and count how many of them are 'Inherent' or 'Acquired' in terms of 'Superpower'.

```
Array #2


Array
(
  [DC Comics] => Array
    (
      [Inherent] => 1
      [Acquired] => 1
    )

  [Marvel] => Array
    (
      [Inherent] => 1
      [Acquired] => 2
    )
)
```

Comment: Where's your code attempt?

Comment: Thor didn't inherit his superpower. He was given the Mjolnir.

Comment: what you want to count ??
array of value or array of same key??

Comment: @Goose this is funny we are talking about code not thor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code without much logic,

```
foreach ($array1 as $val) {
    if(!isset($array2[$val['Franchise']])) {
       $array2[$val['Franchise']] = array('Inherent' => 0, 'Acquired' => 0);
    }
    $array2[$val['Franchise']][$val['Superpower']]++;
}

print_r($array2);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, simple and compact. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

1. `array_column()` function to aggregate an inner key from a 2D array.
2. `array_count_values()` function counts all the values of an array.

Use this code snippet for count values:

```
$a = array ( array ("id" => "101", "Name" => "Superman", "Franchise" => "DC Comics", "Superpower" => "Inherent" ),
   array ( "id" => "908", "Name" => "Batman", "Franchise" => "DC Comics", "Superpower" => "Acquired" ),
   array ( "id" => "228", "Name" => "Wolverine", "Franchise" => "Marvel", "Superpower" => "Acquired" ),
   array ( "id" => "158", "Name" => "Iron Man", "Franchise" => "Marvel", "Superpower" => "Acquired" ),
   array ( "id" => "978", "Name" => "Thor", "Franchise" => "Marvel", "Superpower" => "Inherent" ));
  echo "<pre>";
$return = array();
// first group array values by franchise
foreach($a as $val) {
    if (!isset($return[$val['Franchise']])) {
        $return[$val['Franchise']] = array();
    }
    $return[$val['Franchise']][] = $val;
}
$arr = array();
// count elements by key value pair in particular franchise
foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = array_count_values(array_column($value, 'Superpower'));
    $arr[$key] = $tmp;
}
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo is here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iuae-n4wp)

Answer (score 1):

With single and short [***array_reduce***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
// $arr is your initial array
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($r, $v){
    if (isset($r[$v["Franchise"]][$v["Superpower"]])) {
        $r[$v["Franchise"]][$v["Superpower"]] += $r[$v["Franchise"]][$v["Superpower"]];
    } else {
        $r[$v["Franchise"]][$v["Superpower"]] = 1;
    }
    return $r;
}, []);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [DC Comics] => Array
        (
            [Inherent] => 1
            [Acquired] => 1
        )

    [Marvel] => Array
        (
            [Acquired] => 2
            [Inherent] => 1
        )
)
```